# Maven child dependencies based on profile

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module project and I am trying to change the dependencies of the build in child projects based on what profile is selected. In my "dev" and "prod" profiles, I need maven to include the the mysql library whereas in my "local" profile, I need maven to include the h2 library.

Parent POM

```
<profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <properties>
        <!-- Defines the environment variable -->
            <build.env>local</build.env>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        <!-- Defines the environment variable -->
        <build.env>dev</build.env>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <properties>
        <!-- Defines the environment variable -->
            <build.env>production</build.env>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Data module POM

```
<!-- Local specific dependencies -->
<profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${version.h2}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>build.env</name>
            <value>local</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>

<!-- Dev specific dependencies -->
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mysql}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>build.env</name>
            <value>dev</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>

<!-- Production specific dependencies -->
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mysql}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>build.env</name>
            <value>production</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

The problem is that when building from the root project, switching profiles appears to not affect the child pom and no dependencies are are included in the data module jar file (no profile inheritance?). How do I trigger the child profiles to include the dependencies listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent POM:

```
<profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <properties>
        <!-- Defines the environment variable -->
        <build.env>local</build.env>
        <!-- Define DB dependency type/version -->
        <dbGroup>com.h2databse</dbGroup>
        <dbArtifact>h2</dbArtifact>
        <dbVersion>${version.h2}</dbVersion>
    </properties>
</profile>
[...]
```

Module POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${dbGroup}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${dbArtifact}</artifactId>
    <version>${dbVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

You'll have to move your version.h2/version.mysql definitions to your parent POM, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tonight but I believe that this will work.