# Is there a way to avoid multiple imports on h2 in maven when providing a profile to test locally?

Tags: java, maven

I currently have the following...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    ...
    <dependencies>
       ...
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Is there a way to do this without the multiple imports?

Comment: Why do you have multiple dependencies for the same artifact?

Comment: One is needed to run when testing and one is needed to run when a specific profile is given. This redundancy is what I am trying to avoid hence the final comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may potentially override dependency scopes via properties as was described in [Override maven dependency scope in profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51136345/3426309), in your case that would look like:

```xml
<properties>
  <h2.scope>test</h2.scope>
</properties>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <properties>
      <h2.scope>runtime</h2.scope>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>${h2.scope}</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Moreover, you may even more weird things like [defining "dynamic dependencies"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426305/3426309).

However, despite the fact `maven` allows such setups you are better off with staying clear of them: [maven team](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) defines profile use cases as the last resort of influencing on a build process or environment, in the most cases more convenient options do exist.